# facebook "could not retrieve data from URL"

Tags: facebook, google-app-engine, facebook-graph-api

I'm getting the below error when attempting to make a graph api call to facebook. I know my callback url is fine because when I test it in the facebook debugger, it views the page just fine. I'm also using Google App Engine and I'm really thinking this error might have something to do with the async call coming back from facebook to my GAE app while the thread making the URL Fetch is stil active waiting for the reply.

The error:

```
{"error":{"type":"Exception","message":"Could not retrieve data from URL."}}
```

My code making the call:

```
            URL url = new URL("https://graph.facebook.com/me/");
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url
                    .openConnection();
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                    connection.setConnectTimeout(30000);

            OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(
                    connection.getOutputStream());
            writer.write("access_token=" + access_token + "&activity=" + ogpUrl);
            writer.close();

            if (connection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                log.info("GraphApiHelper: success stream");
            } else {
                log.severe("GraphApiHelper: error stream: "
                        + connection.getResponseMessage());
            }
```

Any thoughts what could be causing this or if GAE behaves strangely on these type of URL Fetches? Iv'e also increased the timeout on the connection in case that was causing the issue. Not sure if it's relevant or not either too, but I think this is a completely generic error from the facebook linter so it could mean a problem with the call itself.

Additionally I can see the Facebook linter making the callback to my GAE app in the logs and I'm not seeing any errors in that response.

Edit: Ok this is clearly a timing out issue. I'm noticing that when a new GAE instance isn't fired up on the facebook linter callback, that it works correctly. When a new GAE instance is fired up, it takes upwards of 50 seconds or so. I get the error back from Facebook within 10 seconds. So something is timing out in that period whether it's the facebook linter or GAE URL Fetch.

Answer (score 0):

I write to FB from GAE all of the time on nimbits.com - no worries there.

This code works:

Server Side Facebook Impl:

https://github.com/bsautner/com.nimbits/blob/master/nimbits-tds/src/com/nimbits/server/external/facebook/FacebookImpl.java

this is my handy http post and get helper class that works on GAE and is referenced in the above code:

https://github.com/bsautner/com.nimbits/blob/master/nimbits-model/src/com/nimbits/server/http/HttpCommonImpl.java

Answer (score 0):

There might be some concurrency issue as well.
See this, it worked well for me.
[Facebook Open Graph from Rails Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9892499/facebook-open-graph-from-rails-heroku?lq=1)