# Facebook Open Graph from Rails Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook-graph-api, heroku

I've been fighting this problem all day, and could really need some input.

I have a Rails application (3.1.3) running on Heroku Cedar, trying to publish some Facebook Open Graph actions with gem fb_graph (2.4.0).

This is my code.

```
begin
    app = FbGraph::Application.new(ENV['facebook_app_id'])
    me = FbGraph::User.me(user.facebook_access_token)

    logger.info "Facebook: User #{user.name} reviewing game #{game_url(review.game)}"

    action = me.og_action!(
        app.og_action(:review),
        :game => game_url(review.game),
        :content => review.review,
        :rating => review.rating
    )
rescue Exception => exc
    logger.error "Failed to publish review #{review.id} to facebook #{user.facebook_auth}"
    logger.error "Facebook error msg: #{exc.message}"
end
```

If I go to the page in my application that will try to run this code, it will fail with the following message.

```
FbGraph::InvalidRequest (Exception :: Could not retrieve data from URL.)
```

But, if I where to open a Heroku console, `heroku run console` and type in the code by hand, it works perfectly.

My first thought was that `game_url(review.game)` where to blame, but after adding the log message, I'm sure that it returns the correct URL. And, since the whole thing works when I run it manually through heroku console it confirms that URL to be accessible and delivering the data requested.

Any feedback or experiences with this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried changing ENV['facebook_app_id'] and including the ID right there? I've had issues with Facebook and environment variables before.

Comment: It was worth a try, but sadly no effect. I also tried adding the secret, even though it shouldn't be needed.

Comment: Upgraded fb_graph to version 2.4.7 with no effect.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Solved it!

Really stupid actually. I had only one web dyno in my Heroku application. Since my only web dyno was doing the Facebook API call, there was no dyno to respond to the Facebook callback. You need at least 2 to get this to work.

The reason the code worked in heroku console was simply because the web dyno was not busy handling my request.

I might push that code to a work queue in the future as it seems more appropriate and let a worker dyno handle the Facebook publishing.

Comment: Note that, even with two dynos, you can still block if the router sends the request to the wrong dyno. I've suggested Unicorn in another answer; another alternative is to use a second app to implement the callback, though I'm not sure if the fb_graph gem is amenable to that.

Comment: @metadaddy, Heroku says that more than one dyno provides more concurrency. If I have two dynos, why is it routing to the same dyno? 
What router sends to the wrong dyno?

Comment: @Tony, the routing layer will distribute requests across your dynos. Let's say you have 2 dynos, and dyno 1 is handling the request described above. A second request arrives (from some user's browser, not from FB) and is routed to dyno 2. Now the request arrives from FB, and could well be routed to dyno 1, which induces the deadlock. Adding a dyno is fine for testing, but it's not a robust longer term solution.

Comment: @metadaddy, even with 5 dynos the facebook callback was sent to the same dyno than the original request. Do you know why?

Comment: @Tony, interesting - I often set up multiple dynos on a Rails app, then refresh the page from my browser a few times, and see the requests distributed across the dynos. Not sure why you're seeing that behavior. You should ask at https://support.heroku.com

Comment: Thanks. If I do what you tell me I can see the requests distributed across the dynos, but on the specific case of the FB callback it uses the same dyno than the original request, so it get blocked.

Comment: I solved the issue changing the heroku's stack to cedar and using unicorn server. I still wonder why it didn't worked with multiple dynos.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to a second dyno might be to try [Unicorn](http://unicorn.bogomips.org/) - that would allow your app to service the second call while the first is blocked.

These articles give some useful detail on getting started with Unicorn:

- [More concurrency on a single Heroku dyno with the new Celadon Cedar stack](http://michaelvanrooijen.com/articles/2011/06/01-more-concurrency-on-a-single-heroku-dyno-with-the-new-celadon-cedar-stack/)
- [Unicorn!](https://github.com/blog/517-unicorn)

Answer (score 0):

The following link seems to suggest this is timeout related, although no actual solution has yet been given. [facebook "could not retrieve data from URL"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9815701/facebook-could-not-retrieve-data-from-url)

You may want to also keep track of answers for the above link.

Comment: Thank you for the link. Good to see I'm not alone. I'm not sure about the timeout thing. It takes ~400ms to render the game_url page. That shouldn't case a timeout right? Worth investigating. Thanks.