# How do you call a model's show url from a Rail create controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, koala

I'm having trouble calling a model's show path from within a create controller.

I'm using the Koala gem in a Rails 3.2 app. I'm trying to publish to Facebook's open graph automatically when a User creates a particular record type.

I have a page set up with all the required FB meta tags.

I can run the Koala methods from the console and everything works fine.

But if I try to run this from the controller I get an error.

My controller looks like this:

```
def create
  @fb_model = current_user.fb_models.build(params[:fb_model])   
  if @fb_model.save
    Koala::Facebook::API.new(app_token).put_connections( current_user.fb_uid, "namespace:action", :object => fb_model_url(@fb_model) ) 
    respond_to do |format| 
      format.html { redirect_to(@fb_model, :notice => 'Successfully created.') }
      format.xml  { render :xml => @fb_model, :status => :created, :location => @fb_model }    
    end
  else
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render :action => "new" }
      format.xml  { render :xml => @fb_model.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

When I create a record, my logs show:

```
Koala::Facebook::APIError (HTTP 500: Response body: {"error":{"type":"Exception","message":"Could not retrieve data from URL."}}):
```

If I edit the controller to use a static url for testing, everything works fine.

```
  ...
  if @fb_model.save
    Koala::Facebook::API.new(app_token).put_connections( current_user.fb_uid, "namespace:action", :object => "http://myapp.com/fb_model/2" ) 
  ...
```

Why can't I pass the record's url to FB from within the create controller using `fb_model_url(@fb_model)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I eventually got to the bottom of this. It's actually a really frustrating issue, as there is no indication that this is the problem in any logs or elsewhere.

The problem was that I was deploying/ testing on Heroku, and only had 1 web dyno running. My app was unable to handle both the Facebook request and the post/ get simultaneously, causing the error.

This has been addressed in another question [Facebook Open Graph from Rails Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9892499/facebook-open-graph-from-rails-heroku). It's really not what I was expecting, and I didn't come across this question in any of my earlier searching. Hopefully this can help someone else.

I solved the issue by switching from thin to unicorn.

Answer (score 0):

build is finalised when the parent model is saved, and you dont seem to be operating on a parent.

I think you actually want this:

`@fb_model = current_user.fb_models.new(params[:fb_model])`

Also you seem to be calling @fb_model.save twice which is wrong.

Comment: Thanks @isotope. I've tried using new in place of build, but I'm still getting a URL error. I've updated my question above. Thanks for any other ideas you may have.

Comment: im not sure, you'd need to have a loko at exactly what fb_model_url is returning, does it include the protocol for instance? I'd try a halfway and see if that works: `:object => "http://myapp.com/fb_model/#{@fb_model.id}"`

Comment: hi isotope, thanks for helping. Sorry I'm being slow, what do you mean by "does it include the protocol?" If I render fb_model_url as text, it is the correct url. The protocol (Facebook?) is defined via the Koala::Facebook::API function, and FB then scrapes info from the FB metatags in the target page's header. I will try your halfway suggestion, and report back. Thanks!!

Comment: URL protol, either 'http://' or 'https://' if it's missing then it might think its a relative link.

Comment: Thanks @isotope. Your suggestions helped me debug this. The issue was no where near what I thought it was! I'll post an answer with details.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for posting your findings - I've been dealing with this issue for the past couple of days and wouldnt have figured that. So when you simply increased your dyno load, you no longer had this error? I was on the verge of just using the Javascript SDK even though my 'put_connections' callbacks work in the heroku console.

Comment: Hi John, I feel your pain. This had me tearing my hair out! As a first step I increased the number of dynos on Heroku. This got things working. As a more cost effective solution, I swapped Thin out for Unicorn, which effectively handles queued/simultaneous requests. Under Unicorn I was able to reduce my dynos back to 1, and still have this work. This is now working perfectly for me in a staging env, have yet to test under any significant loads.

Comment: Seriously, almost two full days of trying every permutation I could think of. I was going to ask how you went about it; thanks for the suggestion. Ill look into Unicorn.